# Accidentally enabled all Apache modules

Tags: php, apache

I have accidentally enabled all Apache modules by running the command:

```
a2enmod *
```

Is there a way to reset the mods to only use the default? I only need a few modules beyond "default" and I can't seem to get anything other than a 403 error on my webserver.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a question for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can list the active modules using...

```
apachectl -M
```

You can also list them using...

```
a2dismod
```

And then you just need to run

```
a2dismod module_to_disable
```

Answer (score 0):

That would depend somewhat on your what operating system you are running, what version of Apache you are running, and what additional libraries and preprocessors you have installed (Perl, PHP, Python, etc), among other things --

Here are a list of modules loaded on my fairly standard Debian 8/Apache 2.4 server, with PHP5 enabled -- If you wanted you could disable all of the modules and enable these individually:

[image]